# Python int method

Tags: python

So I have a code, but i'm not sure how it works:

```
    def getValue(number):
        return int(number,16)
```

So if I were to put in 'a25' for the number it should return 2597 But my question is how does this int function work, and is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works something like this:

```
import string
allChars = string.digits+string.lowercase #get a list of all the 'characters' which represent digits
def toInt(srep,base):
    charMap = dict(zip(allChars,range(len(allChars)))) #map each 'character' to the base10 number
    num = 0 #the current total
    index = len(srep)-1 #the current exponent
    for digit in srep:
        num += charMap[digit]*base**index
        index -= 1
    return num
```

The process with some debugging print for interpreting 'a16' would be:

```
>>> int('a16',16)  #builtin function
2582
>>> toInt('a16',16)
+=10*16^2 -> 2560
+=1*16^1 -> 2576
+=6*16^0 -> 2582
2582
```

Comment: Why is this comment receiving negative vote? The OP did ask for other methods of doing this

Answer (score 4):

Assuming number is in base 16, then this function returns the `int` equivalent of the number.

See this [definition of int method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

Comment: The number is converted *from,* not *to,* hexadecimal.